# $N-1$ equal value principle

Tags: inequality, karamata-inequality

Let us start with an example, consider the following sum: $$H_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n-1+x_i}$$ With $x_1x_2...x_n=1$, We're willing to show that $H_n \le 1$.

To do this we start with the following lemma:

> Lemma: 
>   If a differentiable function has a single inflexion
>   point and is evaluated at n arbitrary reals with a fixed sum, any minimum or maximum must occur where
>   some $n − 1$ variables are equal.

Proof [From mildorf introduction to inequalities]:
Consider $f(y)=\frac{1}{k+e^y}$ for a non-negative constant $k$. We have $f''(y)=\frac{e^y(e^y-k)}{(k+e^y)^3}$, so $f''(y)\ge 0 \iff e^y\ge k$, thus $f(y)$ has exactly one inflexion point at $y=\ln{k}$ and $f$ is convex in the interval $(\ln k,\infty) $. Consider now $y_i=\ln{(x_i)}$ therefore $y_1+y_2+...y_n=0$, and if we take $k=n-1$ we have:$$H_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(y_i)$$ The inflection point will be at $k_0=\ln(k)=\ln(n-1)$ Suppose $y_1 \ge y_2 \ge...\ge y_m \ge k_0 \ge y_{m+1}... \ge y_n $ for some positive $m$. Then by **Karamata's Inequality** (also called **majorization inequality**):$$f(y_1)+f(y_2)+...f(y_m) \le (m-1)f(k_0)+f(y_1+...+y_m-(m-1)k_0) \:\:\:[1] $$
Also by Karamata: $$(m-1)f(k_0)+f(y_{m+1})+...+f(y_n) \le (n-1)f(\frac{(m-1)k_0+y_{m+1}+...+y_n}{n-1}) \:\:\: [2]$$
"otherwise, all of the $y_i$ are less than $k_0$  In that case we may directly apply Majorization
to equate $n-1$ of the $y_i$ whilst increasing the sum in question. Hence, the lemma is
valid"

With this lemma we can prove our inequality quite easly, so I'll skip on that. My question is, in the proof I understood everything up to the very end, I've put quotation marks on the part that confused me, I really don't see his arguement or what he is trying to say in those few lines and I'm kinda lost on why does this prove our initial statement, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Read that as "Suppose ____ for some positive $m$.  Then _____blah blah____.  Otherwise ..."  does that help you see the argument?  If there is no such positive $m$, it is a simple case of every variable being in the concave domain, so maximisation is a trivial case of Karamata (or Jensen).

Comment: Oh wait, I just now realized the magic happens when you add up $[1]$ and $[2]$, also, what you mean is, if there isn't such $m$ then it must be the case that all our points are in an interval in which our function if concave, thus we can just apply Karamata to find that result easly, now, If we actually have a $f$ which is convex and then concave the inverse holds right? say we had $(k-e^y)$ in our second derivative, then the function would archive a minimum when $n-1$ of the variables are equal, did I get this right?

Comment: Yep, that looks right. Now you may want to try your example and see.

Comment: @Spasoje Durovic There is a very nice proof of this inequality by AM-GM. By the way, this inequality is true also by the Vasc's LCF Theorem.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Is the AGM-based proof online somewhere around? Could you give a reference?

Comment: @Hanno I edited it as you suggested :) Personally I didn't find the proof he was talking about but I did find the "Vasc's LCF Theorem" he mentioned, if you're interessed just google "generalization of Jensens Inequality Gazeta Matematica" It should be the second result, it seems quite interessting

Comment: @Hanno It's a beautiful Babak Ghalebi's proof. But I lost the link.

Comment: @Hanno Here you go... http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h224946p1249268